# Some way to create a C# file or class with parameters that work for each stored procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

This may be a silly question, but I am certainly getting frustrated trying to keep up with this code. So I have stored procedures with various parameters. Some have around 20 parameters.

Then in my program, I supply the fields that feed the data for the parameters. Some stored procedure might be used 10 times throughout my program. If I make a change to the stored procedure, then I have to change 10 different C# files to reflect the change. It's tedious, not to mention can cause errors if I forget to update one of the pages.

My C# for example could be like this:

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@PhoneType", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value = phoneType;
```

where `phoneType` is a textfield.

Maybe a class could somehow have all the params set to a value and then my other pages will simply need to have the textfields named appropriately? Help!

Comment: "Some stored procedure might be used 10 times throughout my program" so create one function that is called 10 times - then you only have to change in one place.  Basic OOP.  Encapsulate your data functions into one or more classes for reuse.  Separate your data access from UI code.

Comment: @DStanley I mean on multiple files. page1.cs, page2.cs, page3.cs, etc

Comment: @Ric that is cool, I didn't know that was possible. could help a bit with making it less tedious

Comment: So create classes _outside_ of those pages that can be used by each page.  Again, basic OOP.

Comment: @DStanley Okay I will do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such case, first of all have all DB access code in separate class and in that way DB code changes will happen in only single place.

Secondly, for stored procedure name and parameters names; in one of my project we maintained a class (static class) with all constants to track each procedure and their respective parameters name.

That, way if at all a parameter name is changed; changes will happen in only a single place.

Last but not least, you have procedure with 20 parameters ... that's OK but if in case those are not single parameter but rather can be grouped as single entity then try passing all of them as `DataTable` in C#, it will be of type `SqlDbType.Structured` and in `SQL Server` use table type variable.